# error when attempting to decode data from json file

Tags: json, swift

Json data returning coding keys error when fetching data with my API call. I took the array values that were inside of the json data but for each of the values, I am getting a coding keys error for each array even when I've removed the array from my list.

```
      keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "strMeal", intValue: nil), 
     Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value 
      associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"strMeal\", intValue: 
     nil) (\"strMeal\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

The Json file does not return any coding keys as I have parsed the data with https://app.quicktype.io/
This is the API end point that I am using https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Beef

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with either my fetchJson function, or with my created arrays ?

```
            import UIKit
            @MainActor

         class HomeViewController: UIViewController, ObservableObject {
         @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!
         var meals = [Meal]()
         override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
    
              fetchJSON {
            print("APICompleted")
        
              }
            }

           func fetchJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: 
       "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Beef")!
       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        
            if error == nil {
                 do {
                let meals = try JSONDecoder().decode(Meal.self, from:  data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
            }
             }.resume()
           }
        }

             List of arrays 

                     import Foundation


           struct MealDetailResponse: Decodable {
           let meals: [Meal]
              }

          struct Meal: Decodable {
 
            let strMeal: String
            let strMealThumb: String
            let idMeal: String
          }
```

Comment: let meals = try JSONDecoder().decode([Meal].self, from:  data!)  Didn't somebody say that in your last topic?

Comment: he said "let meals = try JSONDecoder().decode(Meal.self, from:  data!)" I have already updated the suggested format that he stated which cleared the previous error but gave me a coding keys error . But thanks ...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that..but thats the error I did receive.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson are you saying that perhaps this was an Xcode compiler error?

Comment: My bad, it seems the error is correct. But you are decoding the wrong type, use `let meals = try JSONDecoder().decode(MealDetailResponse.self, from:  data!)`

Comment: Unrelated but according to the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) you are encouraged to name the members in the struct `name`, `thumb` and `id`. This avoids unnecessary and redundant information.

Comment: I am using the names that are generated by the API, should I be changing this? & if so, how?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you, that actually worked. Now my only issue is that the table view controller is not showing inside of the simulator